# Generar checkbox jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto que encontre por internet para poder aprender mas y realizar algunas actividades, bueno de hecho queria generar un checkbox para realizar un filtro en mi consulta a la base de datos pero no se como anexarla para realizar el proceso es posible un poco de ayuda para enteder como debo realizarlo, de hecho el archivo busqueda.php realiza la carga de la tabla en mi index.
Mi idea es que el checkbox este marcado y realice un filtro y sino no lo realice pero no se como anexar esto al diseño.

index.php

```
<?php include "conn.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <head>
        <?php include("head.php");?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                        <i class="icon-reorder shaded"></i></a><a class="brand" href="/visorpartes" >Visor Parte Digital</a>
                   
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div><br />

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="content">
                           
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Busqueda de partes</h3> 
                         
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="panel-body"><br>
                            <hr>
                                    <table id="lookup" class="table table-bordered table-hover">  
                                       <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center">
                                        <tr>
      
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Archivo</th>
                                        <th>Fecha</th>
                                        <th>Estado</th>
                                        <th>Paso actual</th>
                                        <th>Ruta respaldo</th>
                                        <th class="text-center"> Acciones </th> 
      
                                       </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <!--/.content-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/.span9-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.container-->
        
        <!--/.wrapper--><br />
        <div class="footer span-12">
            <div class="container">
              <center> <b class="copyright"><a href="http://bpt.cl"> </a> &copy; <?php echo date("Y")?> Visor Parte Digital </b></center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script src="datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#lookup').DataTable( {
                    
                 "language":    {
                    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                    "sSearch":         "Busqueda unidad policial",
                    "sUrl":            "",
                    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primero",
                        "sLast":     "Último",
                        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    }
                },

                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"busqueda.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            $(".lookup-error").html("");
                            $("#lookup").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#lookup_processing").css("display","none");
                            
                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
      
    </body>
```

busqueda.php

```
<?php

 include "conn.php";

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'nombre_archivo', 
    2 => 'created_at',
    3 => 'estado',
    4 => 'paso_actual',
    5 => 'ruta_respaldo'  
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre_archivo, created_at, estado, paso_actual, ruta_respaldo ";
$sql.=" FROM archivo";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("busqueda.php: get InventoryItems");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    // if there is a search parameter
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre_archivo, created_at, estado, paso_actual, ruta_respaldo ";
    $sql.=" FROM archivo";
    $sql.=" WHERE unidad_policial LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";  
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("busqueda.php: get PO");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result without limit in the query 

    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; // $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc , $requestData['start'] contains start row number ,$requestData['length'] contains limit length.
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("busqueda.php: get PO"); // again run query with limit
    
} else {    

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre_archivo, created_at, estado, paso_actual, ruta_respaldo ";
    $sql.=" FROM archivo";
    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("busqueda.php: get PO");
    
}

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["nombre_archivo"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["created_at"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["estado"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["paso_actual"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["ruta_respaldo"];
    $nestedData[] = '<td><center>
                     
                     <a href="visualiza.php?path='.$row['ruta_respaldo'].'&file='.$row['nombre_archivo'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> <i class="menu-icon icon-file"></i> </a>

                     <a href="actualizar.php?id='.$row['id'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> <i class="menu-icon icon-edit"></i> </a>
                     </center></td>';       
    
    $data[] = $nestedData;
    //action="update-edit.php" method="POST"
    //<a href="editar.php?id='.$row['id'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> <i class="menu-icon icon-file"></i> </a>
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

En el caso de la busqueda.php carga y realiza la consulta en linea para poder obtener los cada fila en la tabla pero el archivo index.php no contiene manera para poder agregar el checkbox sin agregar un form al archivo e intento comprender un poco mas el codigo para poder realizar el filtro de checkbox y asi obtener las filas que necesitaria

Comment: No se entiendo lo que dices del checkbox. ¿Cuál es el propósito del mismo? ¿Debe ocurrir algo en baso al marcado/desmarcado del mismo? ¿Qué es lo que quieres filtrar y dónde y por medio de qué archivo? ¿Se debe lanzar otra petición Ajax para dicho filtro?

Comment: Si la idea es que filtre la columna ver_malo cuando esté marcado y cuando esté desmarcado no realice el filtro a mi archivo a la consulta que se encuentra en búsqueda.php pero el problema es cómo agregar dicho checkbox en el index.php

Comment: No se entiende. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para que te expliques mejor, indicando qué es lo que estás intentando y qué problemas o errores tienes. Sé claro en cómo debe actuar el código, pues es confuso lo que explicas. Muchas veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ósea el check lo que quieres es decidir en la consulta en tu busqueda.php si el check esta activado o no en tu vista en html
Puedes verificar si el check esta activo usando el método is() de jQuery o puedes usar en PHP lo siguiente

```
<?PHP 
if( isset($_POST['name_del_checkbox']) && $_POST['name_del_checkbox'] == '1' )
?>
```

De esta forma tendrías una forma de saber si el usuario activo el check en su vista y en base a ello harías lo que necesitas en el archivo de busquedas.php usando esta condicional

En tu HTML tendrías que darle el valor al checkbox ya que el formulario envio o por ajax o por submit del navegador el value del elemento checkbox, en este caso 1, si el check no esta activado no envía su valor de ahí la doble condición de existir el check name y de tener su valor en 1 que significaría que se marco cuando se hizo submit al formulario